# unable to display the http get response from the factory in controller in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

In my service I making http get request as shown below:

```
.factory('InvoicesGeneralService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getAgreementsByCourierId: function (courierId) {  
            console.log("Courier in Services" + courierId);  
            return $http.get('/api/agreements/byCourierId', {params: {courierId: courierId}}).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
          }
        };
    });
```

And in browser console I am seeing the following response :

```
    [
   {
      "id":3,
      "number":"AGR53786",
      "ediNumber":"EDI7365",
      "startDate":"2012-09-02",
      "endDate":"2018-07-01",
      "courier":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"FedEx",
         "url":"www.fedex.com",
         "isActive":true,
         "isParcel":true
      },
      "client":{
         "id":4,
         "code":"KJGTR",
         "name":"Hearty",
         "isActive":true,
         "engageDate":"2011-07-07",
         "isSendRemittance":true,
         "upsUserName":"Tkd",
         "upsPassword":"kuu",
         "isEligibleForTracking":true,
         "isEligibleForAuditing":true,
         "status":5
      }
   }
]
```

And in my controller I am assigning it to result List :

```
  $scope.resultList  =  InvoicesGeneralService.getAgreementsByCourierId(selCourierId);
```

But my `resultList` is always appearing as Empty. Can any one help me, why it is happening?
When I am trying to display `resultList` as shown below, it always shows empty object, `{}`. It supposed to display the response json array from the service but it is showing empty object.

```
<pre class="code"> {{resultList | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise. Anything consuming that data needs to handle it like a promise too.

```
InvoicesGeneralService.getAgreementsByCourierId(selCourierId).then(function(data) {
  $scope.resultList = data;
});
```

Also, your factory's `then` function is not doing anything at the moment. You should return the response's data from it.

```
return $http.get('/api/agreements/byCourierId', {params: {courierId: courierId}}).then(function (response) {
  return response.data;
});
```